# Automatic mailing to warn about file permission change

Tags: permissions, directory, syslinux

I need to receive email notifications if file & folder permissions are modified by a user on one of my Ubuntu servers.

Is such a thing possible? If so how is it accomplished?

Comment: Look into inotify. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html You can google for some simple examples that will meet your requirements. You will want to link notifications to a mail system. http://www.postfix.org/postfix-manuals.html. This is a well-established system that you will find is well documented. And of course you will find more detailed support here once you have questions.